# Not cut the text of a paragraph in the middle

Tags: formatting

I have figure like this

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{figure1.jpeg}
    \caption{text caption here}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

Before this there is a text, however sometimes it cuts the text of the paragraph and keeps the figure and after it the remainder of the text. How is it possible to make in the whole tex make the text doesn't be cut as the described situation?

Comment: Generally insert the code of a figure between paragraphs, the paragraph texts does not wrap around it. Unrelated: it is not a good idea to only supply h, I'd recommend htp, the p is important if the figure is too large for an h or t figure

Comment: Alternatively, use a minipage and \captionof{figure}{...} (caption or capt-of packages).

Answer (score 1):

Easier to show than explain.  `\@captype` is used by `\caption`.  `\intextsep` is the same gap used by figure [h].

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{myfigure}{\begin{trivlist}\vskip\intextsep
  \item\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}\def\@captype{figure}}%
{\end{minipage}\vspace\intextsep\end{trivlist}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is a paragrpahh with a figure in the middle of it
\begin{myfigure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image}
  \caption{Text caption here}
  \label{fig1}
\end{myfigure}
which is treated like an equation in that the sentence is broken and continues normally.
\end{document}
```